# How to work with multiple sessions in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox

I need capability to have two (or more) different sessions, with separate history and bookmarks, but sharing all other config. One for work, one for entertainment.
But I need to keep shared settings and addons.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing -- I just found this:
http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/

and it looks like exactly what I need. Perhaps it will be helpful to you (and others) as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this link ought](http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/multiple-sessions-firefox) to be your solution

> **Excerpts from the article**
>
> There’s two ingredients to getting
>   this to work.
>
> 1. Firefox profiles
> 2. MOZ_NO_REMOTE
>
> To make
>   multiple profiles for Firefox, simply
>   run “Firefox.exe -P” from a command
>   line. This opens up the Profile
>   Manager. Create as many profiles that
>   you feel you’ll need independent
>   sessions. Then create a shortcut to
>   Firefox.exe on your desktop or
>   quickbar for each profile you made.
>   Right click the icon for each shortcut
>   and open the properties window. In the
>   Target field you need to specify which
>   profile to use when launching Firefox
>   like this:

```
“F:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe” -P “ProfileA”
```

> Then just create a new environment
>   variable MOZ_NO_REMOTE with a value of
>   1.
>
> Then you can click each Firefox icon
>   and you’ll have a seperate session for
>   each of your browser windows. Have
>   fun.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by making multiple profile. to know more about profiles in firefox goto http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles . and to know how to make or delete profile goto http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles. hope it will help you.

Comment: Not exactly what I need. Each profile is completely separate, with it's own addons, settings, etc. I need only separate history and bookmarks.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) create two sandboxes each with Full Access to the files with the things you want shared the rest like places.sqlite (Bookmarks/History) will be trapped in the sandbox and viewable to that instance of Firefox only.